# How to generate a single random number given a continuous PDF in Python?

Tags: python, random

I have a given PDF of the number that needs to be generated: **p(z) = N (1 + (1-z)^2) /z**

where **z** is restricted from some minimum **z0** to **1** and proper **N** for normalization.

I need to generate single numbers which follow this distribution and I have no idea where to even start. I have searched around but only found solutions where PDF is for discrete values, not continuous ones.

I have searched for already implemented methods in *numpy* and *scipy* but I have failed to find anything useful, but I might have missed something.

Comment: If you generate a uniform random number between z0 and 1,, and pass that into that function as `z`, doesn't that do it?

Comment: @TimRoberts I have thought about it, and that can't possibly be the solution as, for example, for z0 it would give a possible value higher than 1.

Comment: That function is higher than 1 for every value of z >= 0.  Have you plotted it?

Comment: @TimRoberts I mentioned *proper* N, which in this case with my z0 in my special case means N of about 0.129, so no, the function is not everywhere higher than 1, specially it is equal to N on z = 1, and N < 1

Comment: If you never want a result > 1, then don't you have to define `z0` to match your `N` value?  N=0.129 would require z0=0.21.

Comment: @TimRoberts we get N from z0 such that the cumulative probability is 1, but the function can still go above 1 over a certain small interval, the integral can still be not greater than 1.

Comment: @PeterO. Yeah, it is there to ensure that the integral of the PDF is equal to 1.

Answer (score 2):

Here you have a PDF that is decreasing on a closed interval, namely [z0, 1]. Moreover, the range of the PDF increases as z0 decreases, making a naïve rejection sampler such as the following inefficient:

```
def rejection(z0):
   pdfz0=pdf(z0,z0) # For pdf, see below
   while True:
      x=random.uniform(z0,1)
      if random.random()*pdfz0 < pdf(x,z0):
         return x
```

There is a way to deal with this, though, and this is called the inversion-rejection method, described in Devroye, L., "Non-Uniform Random Variate Generation" (1986), chapter 7, section 4. This method requires finding the PDF and the CDF of the distribution (and also requires the PDF to be decreasing on a closed interval, as is the case here). The following code uses the SymPy library to find the PDF and the CDF.

```
#
# Using SymPy to find the CDF
#

pdfunnorm=((1 - z)**2 + 1)/z
# 1 divided by the `N` in your question (a normalization constant)
pdfnorm=integrate(pdfunnorm,(z,y,1))
ppdf=(pdfunnorm/pdfnorm).simplify()
pprint(ppdf)
pcdf=integrate(ppdf.subs(z,t),(t,y,z)).simplify()
pprint(pcdf)
```

The PDF and CDF can thus be written as follows. An unnormalized PDF is also shown
because the algorithm below works whether or not the PDF is normalized (integrates to 1 on its domain):

```
def unnormpdf(z,y):
   return (1+(1-z)**2)/z

def pdf(z,y):
   return -(2*(z - 1)**2 + 2)/(z*(y**2 - 4*y + 4*math.log(y) + 3))

def cdf(z,y):
   return (y**2 - 4*y - z**2 + 4*z + 4*math.log(y) - 4*math.log(z))/(y**2 - 4*y + 4*math.log(y) + 3)
```

Now we use the inversion-rejection algorithm for decreasing PDFs on [0, 1]. Note that the method shifts some of the variables from [0, 1] to [z0, 1] before passing them to the `unnormpdf` and `cdf` functions. Again `unnormpdf` need not integrate to 1 on its domain.

```
def inversionRejection(unnormpdf, cdf, z0):
   # Devroye, L., "Non-Uniform Random
   # Variate Generation", p. 336.
   u=random.random()
   r=2
   x=1/r
   # NOTE: Here, x is scaled
   # and shifted from [0, 1] to [z0, 1]
   # before passing to CDF
   while u<cdf(z0+x*(1-z0),z0):
      x/=r
   # Version of x that is scaled
   # and shifted from [0, 1] to [z0, 1]
   shiftedx=z0+x*(1-z0)
   while True:
      v=random.uniform(1,r)
      w=random.random()
      y=x*v
      shiftedy=z0+y*(1-z0)
      if w<=unnormpdf(shiftedy,z0)/unnormpdf(shiftedx,z0): # (**)
         return shiftedy
```

In the case of your PDF, certain terms on the right-hand side of `(**)` can cancel out even if the normalized PDF is used, leaving an expression without `log`s and without `z0`:

```
      if w<=shiftedx*((shiftedy - 1)**2 + 1)/(shiftedy*((shiftedx - 1)**2 + 1)):
```

Here are timings on my machine:

```
In [209]: timeit inversionRejection(pdf,cdf,0.001)                                                                    
6.7 µs ± 31.5 ns per loop (mean ± std. Dev. Of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)

In [210]: timeit inversionRejection(unnormpdf,cdf,0.001)                                                              
6.8 µs ± 103 ns per loop (mean ± std. Dev. Of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)

In [211]: timeit rejection(0.001)                                                                                     
129 µs ± 1.77 µs per loop (mean ± std. Dev. Of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)
```

Alternatively, the following algorithm (from Devroye's book p. 312)
takes advantage of the fact that your density is decreasing and
defined on a closed interval. Moreover, it only requires the
(normalized) PDF and not also the CDF.

```
def monbounded(pdf, z0):
   # For decreasing densities on [0, 1]
   m = pdf(0, z0)
   while True:
    u=random.random()
    if u<1/(1+math.log(m)):
      x=random.uniform(0,1/(m))
      if random.random()*m <= pdf(x,z0): return x
    else:
      x=math.exp(u*(1+math.log(m))-1)/m
      if random.random() <= x*pdf(x,z0): return x

def transpdf(x, z0):
   xpos=z0+x*(1-z0)
   return pdf(xpos,z0)*(1-z0)

def transmonbounded(z0):
   # For the PDF in your question.
   # Transform [z0,1] to [0,1].
   return z0+monbounded(transpdf, z0)*(1-z0)
```